# Saving all the log at javascript into java file

Tags: javascript

```
if (speechRecognitionStartTime) {
                let duration = new Date() - speechRecognitionStartTime;
                console.log(`Duration of talk: UID ${volume.uid} +  ${duration} ms`);
            }
            };
```

I have this javascript code that print each UID and the duration they speak into the console.log.
I want to make that if that UID had already speak once for the next duration will be added up into the first duration and it goes on and on so the duration will be the whole time that uid speak.
is it possible to do it at javascript?

Comment: You can't unless your using node js language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the duration for each `UID` in a variable outside of the scope where this code runs.

```
// Assuming you have a durations object defined somewhere
let durations = {};

if (speechRecognitionStartTime) {
    let duration = new Date() - speechRecognitionStartTime;

    // Check if the UID already has a duration recorded
    if (durations[volume.uid]) {
        durations[volume.uid] += duration; // Add the current duration to the existing total
    } else {
        durations[volume.uid] = duration; // Set the current duration as the initial total
    }

    console.log(`Duration of talk: UID ${volume.uid} + ${durations[volume.uid]} ms`);
}
```